Best approach to cache a service
What I want to achieve is to save the data in cache.
My solution:
  public coursesCache;
  public getCourses(): Observable<any> {
    const courses$ = this.coursesCache
      ? of(this.coursesCache)
      : this.courseService.getCourses().pipe(
        tap(courses=> this.coursesCache = courses)
      );

    return courses$;
  }

Is there any problem implementing using this approach?
Is there a better approach to achieve it?

Just use rxjs share operator!
cache = this.courseService.getCourses().pipe(
    share(), // <- changed here!
);

public getCourses(): Observable<any> {
    return cache;
}

You can also directly access the cache property, no need for the method also!

Use shareReplay(1). It will return the last emitted value forever, even to late subscribers. It also shares the stream if there are two or more subscribers at once, so that the courses are only loaded once.
courses$ = this.courseService.getCourses().pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);

